# Mail notifications through Qt on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, email, gmail

I want to write a program which would show a pop up if a new mail arrives through Gmail.

What library/api am I supposed to use get notifications from Gmail pro-grammatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat GMail as an IMAP server and work with it like that. You'll want a C++ IMAP library, there's quite a few out there but I'd start with VMime and avoid libEtPan.